# Resume option in enumitem with \includeonly

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, include, resume

If I use `\includeonly` to include file `foo2.tex`, `\begin{enumerate}[resume]` does not resume the numbering of the last enumerate environment in file `foo1.tex`. What I've done is to run all parts, see what's the last item's number in `foo1.tex` and then write

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\setcounter{enumi}{6}
```

in `foo2.tex`. Is there a way to do this without hardcoding the first item's number in my second, and subsequent, parts?

Comment: This requires a complete change to how `resume` works. As of now, `resume` just picks up the most recent value of `enumi` at compile time. What you're after is to write this value to the file's `.aux` and that `resume` picks it up from there.

Comment: Do you really need the correct numbers? Usually `\includeonly` is for the document preparation stage, where fully correct numbering is seldom a necessity.

Comment: I have prepared notes for my students. The whole set should look like a long list of questions, but I want to hand them out in parts. I want the numbering to start where the last handout left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\include` records the current value of `enumi` (3 here) but not that `enumitem` resume wants to use it, adding a couple of lines to the end of the included (or not included) file fixes that. If you process the entire file then uncomment the `\includeonly` you will get a one page document numbered page 2 with the enumeration numbered 4,5,6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%includeonly{list2}

\begin{document}

\include{list1}


\include{list2}


\end{document}
```

---

list1

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item aaa
\item aaa
\item aaa
\end{enumerate}

\makeatletter
\immediate\write\@partaux{\gdef\string\enit@resume@enumerate{\enit@resume@enumerate}}
\makeatother
```

---

list 2

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume]
\item bbb
\item bbb
\item bbb
\end{enumerate}
```